# make div container adust to svg height

Tags: css, svg

I have this svg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
 <metadata>
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <ellipse cx="106.82" cy="49.373" rx="58.94" ry="49.229" fill="#dc0000" opacity=".183" stroke="#000700" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".30189"/>
</svg>
```

css code:

```
#svg-container {
    background-image: url("/assets/circle.svg");
    background-size: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

reactjs

```
 <div id="svg-container>
   //some text here
 </div>
```

What I want is that div container height adjust to svg height. What I'm doing right now is add padding bottom so that svg won't cut it's height but this is not responsive.

Comment: Your SVG has a ton of white space at the bottom of it so just fix your SVG. Also after that you might find there is a bit of random white space still, in that case set the display to 'block' on the SVG.

Comment: Fixing your SVG means changing the viewBox values.

Comment: @Dominic where will I put the display block in svg?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yup I change the viewbox height value but it's parent div container height value doesn't follow

Answer (score 1):

As @Dominic commented:

> Your SVG has a ton of white space at the bottom of it so just fix your
> SVG.

To make your SVG completely fill the parent container without empty space, you need to set the correct `viewBox` values.

To do this, you can use the JS [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) method, which will show the dimensions of the rectangle bounding the SVG shape.

Add the `x`, `y` coordinate values as well as the `width` and `height` values of the bounding box to the corresponding viewBox parameters:   `viewBox="47.9 0.2 117.8 98.4"`

For responsiveness of your application remove width, height from SVG and add them in relative values to parent container.

```css
#svg-container {
width:25vw;
height:25vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="svg-container">
<svg  version="1.1" viewBox="47.9 0.2 117.8 98.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" style="border:1px solid">
 <metadata>
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title/>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <ellipse id="ellipse" cx="106.82" cy="49.373" rx="58.94" ry="49.229" fill="#dc0000" opacity=".183" stroke="#000700" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width=".30189"/>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
let bb = ellipse.getBBox();
console.log(bb);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make div container adjust to your svg height and width, you can put your svg in the  element

```
 <div>
    <img id="myDiv" src="./assets/circle.svg" alt="">
 </div>
```

But your svg has a big white space below the circle